# change the Y-axis values from Numbers to Strings

Tags: angularjs

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="../../../../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../Scripts/angular.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.chartjs/latest/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div style="height:500px; width:800px" ng-controller="BarChartCtrl">
    <h2>BarChart example</h2>
    <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series"></canvas>
</div> 

<script>
    var app=angular.module('myApp', ['chart.js']);
    app.controller('BarChartCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.labels = ['2014','2015','2016'];

        $scope.series = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'];

        $scope.data = [
          [65, 59, 80],
          [28, 48, 40],
          [30, 0, 0],
          [44, 10, 0],
          [50, 0, 40],
          [66, 50, 0],
          [70, 0, 0],
          [88, 0, 70],
          [90, 30, 0],
          [10, 0, 60],
          [11, 20, 0],
          [12, 0, 90]
        ];
    });
```

In the above code Y-axis values are Numbers and I want to change it to some string in arranged manner so that I can pass the "range" string from $scope.data

Comment: Can you give an example, how do you want that string to be composed?

Comment: Final, Semi-Final, Quarter-Final, R3,R2,R1,Qualification these are the values that I need to put under Y-axis in an arranged manner as Final is first and Qualification is at last.

Comment: Your `data` array has 3 values in each nested array, how is it related to the 7 values you've mentioned?

Comment: sir that thing i will change it later, it is just the sample code

Comment: In the year of 2014, I have months as series and in each month I will be having data like the student grade level as final,semifinal or etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` your array to a desired string array, like this:

```
$scope.rangeArray = $scope.data.map(function(item) {
    return {
      Item.join(",") // join the nested array values to a string separated with a comma for example
    }
  });
```

Each `item` in the `map` function is a nested array in your `data` array. In our example you get a `rangeArray` with nested string arrays.

Comment: sir what about using "strings" at Y-axis

Comment: I have one more Question that I want to fix the size of each single bar.

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJs-Charts we can't able to change Y-axis Integer Values to String Values for Range but in other charts we can able to modify by just appending $ or any such kind of symbols.